# Making RegEx Match Bold - VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

This is my current RegEx: `\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]`

That works perfectly fine, it replaces exactly what I want it to. But, I'm trying to figure out how to make it replace the string between `[b][/b]` with a bold string, but the actual text stays the same.

Example string: `[b]This is an example![/b]`

Desired output: **This is an example!**

I'm using VB.NET and this is what I currently have:

```
Dim reg As New Regex("\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]")
Dim str As String = String.Empty
For Each m As Match In reg.Matches(MainBox.Text)
  str = reg.Replace(MainBox.Text, "test")
Next

Preview.Show()
Preview.RichTextBox1.Text = str
Preview.Size = New Size(Preview.MaximumSize.Width, Preview.MaximumSize.Height)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the start of the selection, and set the attributes of the text before inserting it.

```
Preview.RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = Preview.RichTextBox1.Text.Length
Preview.RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
Preview.RichTextBox1.SelectedText = str
```